# How to use an iterator to print class objects in a list

Tags: c++, class, object, printing

I currently have a program that creates an object. I can see that the object is successfully created with a describe method I have. I put this object into a list by doing this:

```
list<GameObject*> roomObjects5;
auto * obj1 = new GameObject(&o1name,&o1desc,&o1key);
roomObjects5.push_back(obj1);
```

I'm now trying to print through this list called roomObjects 5 using an iterator:

```
  void print(const list<GameObject>& s) {
        list<GameObject>::iterator i;
        for( i = s.front(); i != s.end(); ++i)
            cout << *i << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }
```

However there is an error

> class 'const gameObject' is not compatible with
>   class'list::iterator

and

> Binary operator '<<' cant be applied to the expressions 'ostream' and
>   'GameObject'

and when I run I get the error:

error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
     void print(const list& s) {
                                           ^

> mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles\textadv.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed mingw32-make.exe[2]:** 
>   [CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/all] Error 2 CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe
>   for target 'CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/all' failed mingw32-make.exe[1]:
>    **[CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/rule] Error 2 CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/textadv.dir/rule' failed
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [textadv] Error 2 Makefile:117: recipe for
>   target 'textadv' failed

Could anyone help me please?

Updated:

```
> void print(const list<GameObject>& s) {
>     list<GameObject *>::iterator i;
>     for (i = s.front(); i != s.end(); ++i)
>         cout << *(*i) << " ";
> 
>     cout << endl; }
```

I'm now trying this and i'm getting the error

> Class 'const GameObject' is not compatible with class
>   'list::iterator'

Update 2:

I'm now trying this:

void print(const list& s) {
    list::iterator i;

```
for(auto i = s.front(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    cout << *(*i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
```

}

and getting errors with the

```
i != s.end
```

line

> 'cant compare structures'

and

```
++i
```

> Expression of type GameObject is neither numeric nor a pointer

and

```
*(*i)
```

> 'Pointer type is required'

Comment: You're mixing up pointers. The list holds `GameObject*`  and the iterator points to `GameObject` not `GameObject*`. Moreover, if you have defined operator `<<` on your `GameObject`, you are using it on the pointer. Use `list<GameObject>::iterator i;` and `cout << *(*i) << " ";`

Comment: s/`list<GameObject>::iterator`/`list<GameObject>::const_iterator`

Comment: @everyone I tried this and now I've got:     void print(const list<GameObject>& s) {
        list<GameObject *>::iterator i;
        for (i = s.front(); i != s.end(); ++i)
            cout << *(*i) << " ";

        cout << endl;
    } which gives me the error "class const gameobject is not compatible with class list<gameobject*>::iterator"

Comment: Sorry you should use `list<GameObject*>::iterator i;`. Note the added `*`

Comment: Update the question and the current problems.

Comment: @Everyone sorry for repeated edits I just tried that (look at comment above) and cant figure out why thats not working

Comment: Why don't you remove the whole line `list<GameObject*>::iterator i;` and make the loop start like: `for(auto i = s.front(); i != s.end(); ++i)`. You are passing a `const list` so its iterator has to be `const` in order to make sure nothing is going to change.

Comment: @Everyone I've tried both your solutions and highlighted the issues in the original post

Comment: Anyway, I believe you better use `.begin()` not `front()`

Comment: @Everyone I'm using the code you gave me in the answer which works apart from the  *(*i) which requires a pointer type? What do I put here?

Comment: the first `*i` returns a `GameObject*` which is a pointer. The second `*` is to get the content of `GameObject*` pointer.

Comment: @Everyone this is throwing an error which I specified in my reply to the answer

Comment: Are you overloading `operator <<`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on `list::front()`:

> Returns a reference to the first element in the list container.
>
> Unlike member list::begin, which returns an iterator to this same element, this function returns a direct reference.
>
> Calling this function on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

Instead of using `front()` use `begin()` which returns the iterator. Moreover,
you are passing `const list<GameObject>&` and your original list is `list<GameObject*>`. Your function cannot accept your list. The code would look like:

```
 void print(const list<GameObject*>& s) {
     for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
          cout << *(*i) << " "; 
     cout << endl;
 }
```

---

Update: it seems you are not overloading `ostream& operator << (ostream& out, GameObject& gObj)`. You should define it:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, GameObject& gObj){
    out << gObj.(whatever you want to print out from GameObject);
    return out;
}
```

---

Update 2:

I have made a dummy code for testing and it is working correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Noob {
public:
  int bad_data;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& s, Noob& noob) {
  s << noob.bad_data;
  return s;
}

void print(const list<Noob*> list) {
  for (auto i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i)
    cout << *(*i) << " ";
}

int main() {
  list<Noob*> list;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    list.push_back(new Noob());

  print(list);
  return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: This works apart from the *(*i) bit which says pointer type is required?

Comment: I am guessing you are not overloading the operator << ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, sorry